# Check if db don't have specified items

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to scrape blogs' post and store them into my db. For scheduling scrap I will do conjob on my server. But I'm having problem getting the flow right. I don't want to re-scrape everything, I want to script to check if there is new post then save it into my db.

My challenge is different blogs may have various pattern, I think one of the way is to get the date and the latest post's date in the db. But what if the post don't have a date? compare string? is that a reliable approach?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use their RSS feed? Most of blogs have one and if they do, there is no need for scraping.

RSS is simple XML file which you can read and compare with what you have (like RSS readers).

If their entire post isn't visible in RSS (and probably isn't), then just follow URL from feed and get their post if that's what you want.

Comment: so you are suggesting I scrape their rss? yes it makes my life easier because there are library getting rss data, but I want the posts be saved into my db. Also some of them have broken rss.

Comment: RSS gives you general idea about when posts where added and what their URLs are. You can then go with url of new posts, get post, save it, and go on.

If someone has broken RSS or doesn't have any, then you can either ask them for api, or scrape them normally. But my point is - you don't have to do that every time on every blog since there is RSS out there

Comment: I totally got ur point, but there are hidden information I couldn't get from their rss.